# What's the purpose of the new method int.as_integer_ratio() in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was taking a look at the new features that were implemented in python 3.8, and I found out about a new function `numerator, denominator = x.as_integer_ratio()`. They state in the documentation that it

> Return a pair of integers whose ratio is exactly equal to the original integer and with a positive denominator. The integer ratio of integers (whole numbers) is always the integer as the numerator and 1 as the denominator.

Basically this code

```
x = 10
numerator, denominator = x.as_integer_ratio()

print(numerator)
print(denominator)
```

Output

```
10
1
```

I was just wondering what is the point of having a function that will always return the same value and 1 ? I also saw that it was previously available for `float` which makes sense.

Comment: If you understand the use case for float, then it also makes sense to have a similar method on int that is consistent, so you can use it on both without having to worry about whether your number is an int or a float.

Comment: That was my initial guess. I was just wondering if there was any other reasons why this would be implemented. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the main reason for the changes were to implement uniformity, and typing for mypy, so that an `int` can be a subtype of `float`

> msg313780 - (view)    Author: Raymond Hettinger (rhettinger) * (Python
> committer)    Date: 2018-03-13 21:25
>
> Goal:  make int() more interoperable with float by making a
> float/Decimal method also available on ints.  This will let mypy treat
> ints as a subtype of floats.
>
> See:
> https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-March/152384.html
>
> Open question:  Is this also desired for fractions.Fraction and
> numbers.Rational?

and digging into the pipermail it appears it helps with being able to change the domain of a type via decomposition, etc:

> [Python-Dev] Symmetry arguments for API expansion Guido van Rossum
> guido at python.org Tue Mar 13 15:07:15 EDT 2018
>
> ```
> Previous message (by thread): [Python-Dev] Symmetry arguments for API expansion
> Next message (by thread): [Python-Dev] Symmetry arguments for API expansion
> Messages sorted by: [ date ] [ thread ] [ subject ] [ author ]
> ```
>
> OK, please make it so.
>
> On Tue, Mar 13, 2018 at 11:39 AM, Raymond Hettinger <
> raymond.hettinger at gmail.com> wrote:
>
> > > On Mar 13, 2018, at 10:43 AM, Guido van Rossum  wrote:
> > >
> > > So let's make as_integer_ratio() the standard protocol for "how to make
> > > a Fraction out of a number that doesn't implement numbers.Rational". We
> > > already have two examples of this (float and Decimal) and perhaps numpy or
> > > the sometimes proposed fixed-width decimal type can benefit from it too. If
> > > this means we should add it to int, that's fine with me.
> >
> > I would like that outcome.
> >
> > The signature x.as_integer_ratio() -> (int, int) is pleasant to work
> > with.  The output is easy to explain, and the denominator isn't tied to
> > powers of two or ten. Since Python ints are exact and unbounded, there
> > isn't worry about range or rounding issues.
> >
> > In contrast, math.frexp(float) ->(float, int) is a bit of pain because it
> > still leaves you in the domain of floats rather than letting you decompose
> > to more more basic types.  It's nice to have a way to move down the chain
> > from ℚ, ℝ, or ℂ to the more basic ℤ (of course, that only works because
> > floats and complex are implemented in a way that precludes exact
> > irrationals).
> >
> > Raymond

see:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue33073

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes)

*This minor API extension makes it possible to write numerator, denominator = x.as_integer_ratio() and have it work across multiple numeric types.*

This method was already available on several types such as `float`. Now code using this method works with more types. File it under duck typing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function that takes a parameter and operates on it as a fraction:

```
def foo(x):
    # ...
    num, denom = x.as_integer_ratio()
    # ...
```

Prior to 3.8 we could only call this with a float:

```
foo(3.14)
```

but now we can call it with an int and get reliable behavior:

```
foo(42)
```